# Dropzone remove previous image

Tags: javascript

I'm needing help with an answer to a previous question
[How to limit the number of dropzone.js files uploaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048825/how-to-limit-the-number-of-dropzone-js-files-uploaded/19057630#19057630)

where there was a solution to use

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  accept: function(file, done) {
    console.log("uploaded");
    done();
  },
  init: function() {
    this.on("addedfile", function() {
      if (this.files[1]!=null){
        this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
      }
    });
  }
};
```

But being a js numpty, I don't know where to put this. I assume that my form must have the id myAwesomeDropzone and that the code above needs to be slotted into the dropzone.js document, but where? if you could provide a 'after' and 'before' or replace answer please.

If someone could give me some pointer it'd be great.

My reputation is less than 50 so I couldn't comment on the original thread. If me posting this as a new thread is wrong, please admins don't just chastise me and close it, but move it or do whatever to allow people to provide help accrodingly.

Cheers
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Your html form should be like below. Notice that the

> class="dropzone"

and

> id="my-dropzone"

The "my-dropzone" ID is important , DropZone takes this as "myDropzone" , ( hyphen removed and camelcased ). So when you refer to this id in DropZone.options , it should be "myDropzone". This is very important.

```
<div>
    <form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone" style="border:2px dotted #337ab7">
      <div class="dz-message">
        Drag n drop photos here or click to upload.
        <br />
        <span class="note">(The photos are uploaded to twitter only when the tweet is sent.)</span>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Your should link the css and js file in your html page like so

```
<script src="./js/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<link href="./css/dropzone.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

On the page load , you should init the dropzone configuration in your JS code for your page as below. I am restricting dropzone to accept only one file and its size should not exceed 5MB.

> self.options.maxFilesize = 5; self.options.maxFiles = 1;

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
  init: function() {
    var self = this;
    // config
    self.options.addRemoveLinks = true;
    self.options.autoProcessQueue = false;
    self.options.maxFilesize = 5;
    self.options.maxFiles = 1;
    self.options.dictFileTooBig =
      "Twitter do not allow files greater than 5MB.";
    //New file added
    self.on("addedfile", function(file) {
      console.log('new file added ', file.path);
    });
    self.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) {
      alert(
        "Only one photo can be attached with the tweet."
      );
    });

  }
};
```

Now when your page loads , you will see the form & get the drag n drop functionality in your div.

To access the files you can do like below in the javascript on some button click event.

```
// to get queued files
var myDropzone = Dropzone.forElement("#my-dropzone");
var files = myDropzone.getQueuedFiles();
```