# How to disable clickable the form with Dropzone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm using `Dropzone.js` to upload files to the server. I setting up my Dropzone `maxFiles` parameter to 10 and I was tried this:

```
$('.dropzone').dropzone({
    maxFiles: 10,
    init: function() {
        this.on('maxfilesreached', function() {
            $('.dropzone').unbind('click');
        });
    }
});
```

...but not working. What is the solution to remove clickable from .dropzone or any other way to prevent user to add more files?

Comment: better approach here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19057630/1178072

Comment: @zsitro Yes. That's a cool approach. But I don't see how that disables the clickable form (the question posed). What am I missing?

Comment: @netdjw Excellent question. The clickable attribute doesn't seem to be working either.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Why do not you just use CSS to disable the click event.
When max files is reached, Dropzone will automatically add a class of `dz-max-files-reached`.

Use css to disable click on dropzone:

```
.dz-max-files-reached {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer--it's the most elegant solution I've seen for this.

Comment: @XuDing Excellent answer. I was looking for a way to achieve this for ages but with no luck. CSS did the trick! Thank you.

Comment: When displaying "Remove Links" additionally use `.dz-remove { pointer-events: all; cursor: default; }` to keep them clickable.

Comment: just keep in mind `pointer-events` only work for IE11 and above... okok, it's just me who have to stumble around with this crappy old IE versions. but though ;)

Comment: Great solution! very fast and auto disable without adding extra code.

Comment: I not really agree with this, for me css should only get styles not comportements :-/

Comment: With this solution, I can still drop more files onto the _dropzone_.

Comment: It's old version DropzoneJs. How use in new verisons?

Answer (score 16):

This works PERFECTLY!!! and works on 4.0.1

```
//disable the click of your clickable area
$(".dz-hidden-input").prop("disabled",true);

//enalbe the click of your clickable area
$(".dz-hidden-input").prop("disabled",false);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: This does not fire the dropbox disable and enable events, and therefore keeps history of previous session.

Comment: I've been struggling for hours, thank you. Would be better to have "beforeSelectingFiles" event in this plugin

Answer (score 13):

```
myDropzone.on('maxfilesreached', function() {
    myDropzone.removeEventListeners();
});
myDropzone.on('removedfile', function (file) {
    myDropzone.setupEventListeners();
});
```

Don't forget init _updateMaxFilesReachedClass if you have files from your server.

```
myDropzone._updateMaxFilesReachedClass()
```

Answer (score 3):

If `clickable` option is set to `true`, the dropzone element itself will be clickable, if `false` nothing will be clickable.

You can also pass an HTML element, a CSS selector (for multiple elements) or an array of those. In that case, all of those elements will trigger an upload when clicked.

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div.dropzone", { url: "/file/post", clickable: false });
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an option field on the Dropzone object called `clickable` that defaults to `true`.

Depending on your scenario you can either set this to `false` when you register your Dropzone instance or you can update the value at runtime as needed.

Comment: You can set this, but it does nothing. Dropzone is still clickable.

Comment: This worked perfectly for what I was wanting to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is: myDropzone.disable();

Answer (score 1):

Here we go, updated based on comments below.

How to disable the dropzone "click to open file dialog box" event when maxFiles is reached:

```
$('.dropzone').dropzone({
    maxFiles: 10,
    init: function() {
        this.on('maxfilesreached', function() {
            $('.dropzone').removeClass('dz-clickable'); // remove cursor
            $('.dropzone')[0].removeEventListener('click', this.listeners[1].events.click);
        });
    }
```

I don't know how reliable the "1" in `this.listeners[1]` is, but that's where the click event function lives in my current dropzone configuration.

Comment: I want to disable only after user activated the `maxfilesreached` event. This is not a good solution for me.

Comment: I've been experimenting with `maxfilesexceeded` but it appears to fire after the `maxFiles` has been exceeded, i.e., after adding file #11.

Comment: and what aabout the `maxfilesreached` event listener? I think this fire when I added the 10th file. Yes?

Comment: @zsitro Please elaborate the problem you're having with the solution. I don't understand. I tested it again and it still appears to answer the OP's question.

Comment: if you reach max files and you use this technic there is no way to remove a file and replace it with another one which can be a usecase.

Comment: @zsitro Thanks for the response. However I think the use case you describe is broader than the OP's specific question: "How to disable clickable the form with Dropzone.js?" and request for "any other way to prevent user to add more files". And the response I gave does address that, even though there may be better solutions if the OP steps back and reconsiders the bigger picture in his design.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I achieved this:

```
$('.dz-message').html('<span class="text-center"><span class="font-lg visible-xs-block visible-sm-block visible-lg-block"><span class="font-lg"><i class="fa fa-caret-right text-danger"></i><i>Maximum uploads have been reached</i></span></span></span>');
$('.dropzone').removeClass('dz-clickable');
$('.dropzone')[0].removeEventListener('click', myDropzone.listeners[1].events.click);
$('.dropzone')[0].removeEventListener('drop', myDropzone.listeners[0].events.drop);
$('.dropzone')[0].removeEventListener('dragstart', myDropzone.listeners[0].events.dragstart);
$('.dropzone')[0].removeEventListener('dragenter', myDropzone.listeners[0].events.dragenter);
$('.dropzone')[0].removeEventListener('dragover', myDropzone.listeners[0].events.dragover);
$('.dropzone')[0].removeEventListener('dragleave', myDropzone.listeners[0].events.dragleave);
$('.dropzone')[0].removeEventListener('dragend', myDropzone.listeners[0].events.dragend);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Dropzone object has clickable field. That default value is true.

Depending on your scenario you can either set this to false.

```
    $('.dropzone').dropzone({
     maxFiles: 10,
     clickable: false,
     init: function() {

     }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

@XuDing's Answer works like a charm, but I had an edge case where I wanted to keep remove links working so adding an extended solution for that.

Add below CSS classes

```
.dz-max-files-reached {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
.dz-remove { 
    pointer-events: all; cursor: default; 
}
```