# Dropzone.js - maxFiles = 1 does not stop from dragging multiple files

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dropzone.js

Using Dropzone.js and here's the code.
The option "maxFiles = 1" does prevent selecting multiple files when browsing but does not stop from 'dragging' multiple files onto the dropzone area. Any idea how to prevent multiple file on drag?

```
$(".dropzone").dropzone({
    dictDefaultMessage: "Drag image here",
    uploadMultiple: false,
    parallelUploads: 1,
    clickable: true,
    maxFiles: 1,
    url: 'somewhere' // Provide URL
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048825/how-to-limit-the-number-of-dropzone-js-files-uploaded

Comment: @PardeepDhingra - that didn't seem to solve the problem of dragging files onto the dropzone element.

Answer (score 11):

Please add the below code ,

```
init: function() {
 this.on('addedfile', function(file) {
  if (this.files.length > 1) {
   this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
  }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Why do not you just use CSS to disable the click event. When max files is reached, Dropzone will automatically add a class of dz-max-files-reached.

Use css to disable click on dropzone:

```
.dz-max-files-reached {
      pointer-events: none;
      cursor: default;
}
```

I just tested and this prevents dragging as well.

Credit: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29392241/5830835)

Comment: The problem is this stops dragging or clicking to move files completely, the OP wants to be able to drag or click files in but only one at a time.