# Dropzone Max File

Tags: jquery, html, upload, dropzone.js

I use dropzone for multi purpose. But i have to upload just one file at my project's a part. But i can't it. Can i do select just one file or something?
My code is that.. Thank you...

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="/js/dropzone-test/css/dropzone.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dropzone-test/dropzone.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone">
      <div class="fallback">
        <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
      </div>
    </form>

</body>
<script>
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  maxFiles: 1,
  accept: function(file, done) {
    console.log("uploaded");
    done();
  },
  init: function() {
    this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
        alert("No more files please!");
    });

    this.on("maxfilesreached", function(file){
        alert("No more files please!");
    });

  }
};
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: so above the code you can select multiple file and upload ah ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048825/how-to-limit-the-number-of-dropzone-js-files-uploaded

Answer (score 0):

The `dropzone.js` file contains

```
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions = {}
```

In that section you have to modify maxFiles from:

```
maxFiles: null,
```

to

```
maxFiles: 1,
```