# How do I detach Dropzone programmatically?

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

I use Dropzone to upload files client side. I have set up Dropzone programmatically using JQuery and I would like to be able to detach it so the user can no longer upload anymore files. My ideal solution is to simply make it unclickable then apply a default message to indicate to the user they have exceeded the number of uploads.

Here is a simple example:
http://www.dressorganic.co.uk/dropzone-test/turn-off-dropzone-after-load.htm

Here I try to make it unclickable after the success event but nothing happens.

Here is a link to what I actually want it to look like after a successful upload:
http://www.dressorganic.co.uk/dropzone-test/dropzone-disabled.htm

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Turn off Dropzone after load</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/dropzone-test/dropzone/4.0.1/dist/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dropzone-test/dropzone/4.0.1/dist/min/dropzone.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(function() {

       $("#upload1").dropzone({
          createImageThumbnails : false,
          url: "/dropzone-test/handleupload.asp",
          acceptedFiles : ".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif",
          dictDefaultMessage : "Click here or drag and drop files to upload",
          addRemoveLinks : false,
          success : function(file) {
             this.removeAllFiles();

             $("#upload1").dropzone({
                 clickable : false,
                 url: "/dropzone-test/handleupload.asp",
                 dictDefaultMessage : "You have exceeded the number of uploads, please remove existing to add more"
              });

          },
        });

    });  // JQuery
    //]]>
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="singleproductload">

            <div id="upload1" class="dropzone">

            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you replace or hide the the element with another div with same CSS. Try [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/), [replaceWith](https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/), [show](https://api.jquery.com/show/), [hide](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) or [toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: I am aware I can do this but what I would like to do specifically is detach dropzone then attach it again with new parameters so it becomes unclickable and the new message appears.

Comment: have you tried [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/), [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/), [undelegate](http://api.jquery.com/undelegate/) or [die](http://api.jquery.com/die/)?

Answer (score 0):

See [How to limit the number of dropzone.js files uploaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048825/how-to-limit-the-number-of-dropzone-js-files-uploaded). You don't want to destroy or hide important dropzone elements if you are going to be allowing your users to remove files after they have hit the maximum.

Comment: I actually generate my own script which lists all the uploaded files and allows you to remove them or add captions. This is why I wanted to disable Dropzone. I therefore only allow one file to be upoaded at a time before removing the thumbnail then listing all the upoading files.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing and re-creating div container along with destroy() method. It makes possible re-initialization of Dropzone with new parameters.

```
var url = 'myurl',
    dz

function createDrop(opt) {
    dz && dz.destroy()
    $('#dz_container').find('div').remove()
    $('<div>', {'class':'dropzone',id:'dz'}).appendTo($('#dz_container'))
    Dropzone.options.dz = opt
    dz = new Dropzone('div#dz', { url: url})
}

createDrop({dictDefaultMessage:'new message...'})
```