# dropzone.js maxfilesexceeded event not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

I have been looking around and playing for a little while now with the dropzone.js library and cannot get the [maxfilesexceeded event](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-maxfilesexceeded) to fire. I have looked at the [How to limit the number of dropzone.js files uploaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048825/how-to-limit-the-number-of-dropzone-js-files-uploaded) post for info and have updated to the latest version of the library but the event still wont fire.

I am initialising the listener in the init() function as suggested in the post above. I am able to catch the `maxfilesreached` event but not the `maxfilesexceeded` event

```
$scope.fileUploadConfig = {
    options: {
        url: uploadFileURL,
        maxThumbnailFilesize: 200,
        maxFiles: 5,
        uploadMultiple: false,
        acceptedFiles: "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text,application/rtf,application/pdf,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/vnd.ms-excel,.xls,.xlsx,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation,.ppt,.pptx,image/*,.mp3,.m4a,.ogg,.wav,.wma",
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        paramName: "file",
        dictRemoveFile: "Remove",
        clickable: true,
        previewTemplate: $("#dropzone-preview-template").html(),
        init: function() {
            var instance = this,
                selectedPageId = 0;

            instance.on("success", function(event, data) {
                /* ... */
            });

            instance.on("addedfile", function() {
                /* ... */ 
            });

            instance.on("removedfile", function(file) {
                /* ... */
            });

            instance.on("maxfilesreached", function(file) {
                alert("MAX_FILES_REACHED");
            });

            instance.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) {
                alert("MAX_FILES_EXCEEDED");
            });
        }
    }
};
```

All the code is working as expected except for the maxfilesexceeded event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create this test case bellow:

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = true;
Dropzone.options.fbDropZone = {
    init: function () {
        instance = this;
        instance.on("maxfilesreached", function(file) {
                alert("MAX_FILES_REACHED");
        });
        instance.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) {
                alert("MAX_FILES_EXCEEDED");
        });
    },
    previewTemplate: '<div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview"><div class="dz-details"><div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name></span></div><div class="dz-size" data-dz-size></div><img data-dz-thumbnail /></div><div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div><div class="dz-success-mark"><span>✔</span></div><div class="dz-error-mark"><span>✘</span></div><div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div></div>',
    paramName: "file",
    maxFiles: 1,
    autoProcessQueue: false
};
```

```css
#drop_zone {
    width: 50%;
    border: 2px dashed #BBB;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #BBB;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.js"></script>
<div id='drop_zone'>
    <form action="/uploads.php" class='dropzone' id='fbDropZone'></form>
</div>
```

When you hook dropzonejs with angularjs, you better create a directive for dropzonejs

Comment: Hi Bowen, this works for the maxfilesreached event but have you been able to run it with the maxfilesexceeded event. In my questions I wrote that this event works fine but not the maxfilesexceeded. Also as the directive works and all other events are fired ok, I dont see the benefit in adding it to a directive.

Comment: @SM3RKY, i just added "maxfilesExceeded" event, it fires when the second file is to be uploaded.

Comment: Thanks for your help man, I will look into it a bit further when I get a chance but for now will up-vote your answer. Unfortunately it'll only counter whoever just down voted it

Comment: Was anyone ever able to make this work? This doesn't fire for maxfilesexceeded for me either (works correctly for maxfilesreached though).