# How can I create file uploader with just upload single image in Dropzone

Tags: jquery, html, dropzone.js, dropzone

I create a file uploader with Dropzone.js

```
<div id="dropzone"></div>
```

and jquery code:

```
$("#dropzone").dropzone({
    url: '/',
    multiple:false,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    paramName: "file",
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictRemoveFile: '<span class="fa fa-close"></span>',
    acceptedFiles: 'image/jpeg',
});
```

But when I render page I can select multiple image. I want users just select one image and when they again select other imageT second image replace with first image.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048825/how-to-limit-the-number-of-dropzone-js-files-uploaded

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan In your link image preview show but cant upload, I want don't show more than one image

Answer (score 0):

Edit your jquery code:

```
$("#dropzone").dropzone({
    url: '/',
    multiple:false,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    paramName: "file",
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictRemoveFile: '<span class="fa fa-close"></span>',
    acceptedFiles: 'image/jpeg',
    init: function() {
      this.on("addedfile", function() {
        if (this.files[1]!=null){
          this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
        }
      });
    }
});
```